# Chrome Mobile - .focus not working after alert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-android

I am trying to focus an input element after an alert message in Google Chrome on Android.

The problem is that the focus isnt set on the input element. The keyboard opens but I cant type anything in.

This is my input:

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

I am trying to focus the input on button click

```
const btn = document.getElementById('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert("Some information")
    const input = document.getElementById('input')
    input.focus()
})
```

I tried to add a timeOut to focus but it didnt work.

Is this a Chrome Mobile problem? Because in Firefox Mobile its working as expected.

Comment: At the beginning of your quesiton, you mentioned having `alert(...)`, but there's no `alert` in the code you posted. Can you post your exact code, trimmed down to the relevant part?

Comment: @FiddlingAway Sorry, I forgot the alert - I edited the question

Without the alert it also focuses in Chrome, but with alert its not working

Comment: So the `alert` is causing the issue. You need to replace it with something else - display that information in a `div` with `position: fixed`, for example. Or in a modal of your own making. Then, once the user dismisses the notification / modal, focus back to the input.

Comment: Just tested the code on my smartphone (iOS), it works just fine on Safari and Chrome, but you mentioned using “Android”; Have you tested it on another Android Device?

Comment: @maiakd Tested it on my smartphone (S22 Ultra) and another android device - in both cases it didnt work

Comment: Can you try `confirm()` instead of `alert()`: `if (confirm('Some information')){input.focus() }`? I don't have an android nearby today to do the testings myself

Comment: @FiddlingAway Adding a custom modal is a great idea. 
I confirm that I found that issue on Android device.
Thanks.